# Backbone or javascript Object extend bug

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In comments is output. This is javascript bug, backbone or other?

```
var t = Backbone.View.extend({
    ben: {},
    banana: function(s){
        this.ben[s] = s;
    },
    show: function(){
        console.info(this.ben)
    }
});
var c1 = new t();
var c2 = new t();
c1.banana('1');
c1.show(); //Object { 1="1"}
c2.banana('2');
c1.show(); //Object { 1="1", 2="2"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is behaving as expected (i.e. not a bug). `ben` is added to the [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).

Consider doing this instead:

```
var t = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.ben = {};
    }
    banana: function(s){
        this.ben[s] = s;
    },
    show: function(){
        console.info(this.ben)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, `ben` is a "class attribute" (not really because there are no classes in javascript, but it acts like one).

Everytime you do a `new t()` you're referencing the same `ben`.